# How can I use thymeleaf3 in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependencies, thymeleaf, config

In order to use thymeleaf3, how should I configure it in the "pom.xml" file? The default version of spring boot is thymeleaf2

I checked the relevant documents on the Internet, but some methods I found could not be used. According to the settings in the thymeleaf official website, I can not successfully use thymeleaf.

Here is the dependencies, but it doesn't work:

```xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

and this(change the edition) doesn't work neither:

```xml
<properties>  
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>  
  <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>  
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>  
  <thymeleaf.version>3.0.2.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>  
  <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.0.4</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>  
</properties>
```

Comment: if you use the current spring-boot version, thymeleaf version is 3.

Comment: Oh, really? Thanks, I will try, thanks again!